# fopen: Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in

Tags: php, fopen

I cannot seem to be able to figure out why I receive:
Fatal error: Can't use function return value in write context in [path]/admincp/global.php(226) : eval()'d code on line 12
when I try to use fopen/fsockopen, and such functions to retrieve remote data.

My code is:

http://pastebin.com/crLB429N

I have tried using fopen/fread, and fsockopen/fgets. I don't even know where to start to debug this.

I would appreciate any help given, thank you!

Comment: I just ran your code and didn't get any errors, have you missed something? I'm assuming the backticks in your question are due to trying to make it look like code, rather than the actual code you pasted. Otherwise, please keep in mind backticks execute on the server. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php

Comment: This is the full code: http://pastebin.com/crLB429N

I do not believe I missed anything, and you are correct about trying to get the backticks to work in the question haha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[empty()](https://www.php.net/empty) can only evaluate variables - not function return values. Your first conditional is using `empty(ini_get(...))`

Try:

```
$base_dir = ini_get('open_basedir');

if(function_exists('curl_init') && !ini_get("safe_mode") && empty($base_dir))
```

Comment: I never would've thought about that! Thank you!

Comment: That's a bad use of `empty`. Simply do `... && !ini_get('open_basedir')` instead. See [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/) for why.